# R: using mapply for a function of two vectors

Tags: r, mapply

I have an R function that calculates the Hamming distance of two vectors:

```
Hamming = function(x,y){
get_dist = sum(x != y, na.rm=TRUE)
return(get_dist)
}
```

that I would like to apply to every row of two matrices M1, M2 without using a for loop. What I currently have (where L is the number of rows in M1 and M2) is the very time-consuming loop:

```
xdiff = c()
for(i in 1:L){
    xdiff = c(xdiff, Hamming(M1[i,],M2[i,]))
}
```

I thought that this could be done by executing

```
mapply(Hamming, t(M1), t(M2))
```

(with the transpose because mapply works across columns), but this doesn't generate a length L vector of Hamming distances for each row, so perhaps I'm misunderstanding what mapply is doing.

Is there a straightforward application of mapply or something else in the R apply family that would work?

Comment: A matrix in `R` is a vector. If you would have the rows of the matrices as elements in two lists, then this could work

Comment: I thought this would be the case. Could the issue be due to the fact that M1,M2 were data frames rather than matrix data classes, and should this matter for mapply?

Comment: An `m`-by-`n` data frame is stored as a length-`n` list of length-`m` vectors, and would be handled by `mapply` like any other length-`n` list. How `mapply` handles data frames happens to be irrelevant here, because the transpose of an `m`-by-`n` data frame is an `n`-by-`m` matrix, not an `n`-by-`m` data frame. Try, e.g., `is.matrix(t(data.frame(a=1:2, b=1:2)))`.

Comment: Thanks - I had assumed that an m x n matrix would have been stored as an m-length vector whose elements were n-length vectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `dim(M1)` and `dim(M2)` are identical, then you can simply do:

```r
rowSums(M1 != M2, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Your attempt with `mapply` didn't work because `m`-by-`n` matrices are stored as `m*n`-length vectors, and `mapply` handles them as such. To accomplish this with `mapply`, you would need to split each matrix into a list of row vectors:

```r
mapply(Hamming, asplit(M1, 1L), asplit(M2, 1L))
```

`vapply` would be better, though:

```r
vapply(seq_len(nrow(M1)), function(i) Hamming(M1[i, ], M2[i, ]), 0L)
```

In any case, just use `rowSums`.

Comment: What is the advantage of using vapply rather than mapply in your examples above? The rowSums alternative works fine for this specific example, but I made up the Hamming distance example in order to ask a broader question of how to use apply for vectors in two matrices, so mapply/vapply are the best general solutions.

Comment: The `mapply` call has more overhead, for a few reasons:  (1) `mapply` requires memory for all of the row vectors to be allocated up front and for the entire duration of the call, whereas `vapply` only uses one row vector at a time. (2) `mapply` constructs an intermediate list containing all of the results, before unlisting them into an array, whereas `vapply` copies results as they are generated into a preallocated array. (3) Each `asplit` call involves an R level `for` loop, which is quite slow.